# How to a resize a dynamic array?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a dynamic array:

```
int* p;
ifstream inFile("pop.txt");
int x;

while (inFile >> x)
{
    // ????
}
```

How do I resize `p` so I am able to to fit `x` in as like an array. I don't want to use a vector or static array as I am trying to learn the language. I need to use pointers because I don't know the initial size. Any attempt is appreciated.

Comment: Why a double pointer? Your requirements only indicate the need for a single level of redirection.

Comment: The higher level data C++ library components (like `std::string` and `std::vector<int>`) were created so that these kind of problems can be taken care of in a simple, safe, and standard way. So learning to use these components is the right way to learn C++.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest answer is that you should use higher level components than raw arrays and raw memory for the reading. That way the library will handle this for you. A simple way of reading a set of numbers into an application (without error handling) could be done with this simple code:

```
std::vector<int> data;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(inFile), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(data));
```

The code creates a couple of input iterators out of the stream to read `int` values, and uses a `back_inserter` iterator that will `push_back` onto the vector. The vector itself will manage growing the memory buffer as needed.

If you want to do this manually you can, you just need to allocate a larger chunk of memory, copy the first N elements from the old buffer, release the old buffer and continue reading until the larger buffer gets filled, at which point you follow the same procedure: allocate, copy, deallocate old, continue inserting.

Comment: As I said I don't want to use a vector. Besides, doesn't the vector do something internally to resize the array? That's  exactly what I'm asking about.

Comment: If you want a piece of advice, first learn the language from a high level perspective, then when you understand how things work consider going deeper into the details. Don't reinvent the wheel, `std::vector` exists, and is well rounded. Chances are that while attempting to mimic the behavior you will end up with a square-ish wheel, and the worse part is that you might not even notice the irregularities and start believing that all wheels have 6 sides.

Comment: As an alternative to `vector<int>`, a `deque<int>` will give an interface very much like an array, without the "allocate new, copy from old, free old" resizing logic. What it loses is contiguity of the `int`s, but may waste less memory than `vector<>` (depending on how the resizing logic of the `vector<>` is implemented).

Answer (score 2):

You can't resize it. All you can do is allocate a new bigger array, copy everything over from the old array to the new array, then free the old array.

For instance (untested code)

```
int array_size = 10;
int* array = new int[array_size];
int array_in_use = 0;
int x;
while (in >> x)
{
    if (array_in_use == array_size)
    {
        int* new_array = new int[2*array_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
            new_array[i] = array[i];
        delete[] array;
        array = new_array;
        array_size *= 2;
    }
    array[array_in_use++] = x;
}
```

It's tedious, and I'm not convinced it's a good thing for a beginner to be doing. You'd learn more useful stuff if you learned how to use vectors properly.

Comment: How would I do that? Can you give an example?

Comment: As I already mentioned in a comment in my answer... reinventing the wheel is prone to *irregularities*. In this case: `new_array = array;` should be `array = new_array;` and `array_size` is not updated appropriately after the size has grown (missing `array_size *= 2;`)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Thanks for the correction. I agree completely but the OP did ask.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* always use [realloc()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc). It's a part of the C Standard Library, and the C Standard Library is a part of the C++ Standard Library. No need for tedious `new`s and `delete`s.

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


int main(void)
{
    int* array = nullptr;
    unsigned int array_size = 0;

    std::ifstream input("pop.txt");
    for(int x; input >> x;)
    {
        ++array_size;

        int* array_failsafe = array;
        array = static_cast<int*>(realloc(array, sizeof(x) * array_size));
        if(array == nullptr)
        {
            std::cerr << "realloc() failed!" << std::endl;
            free(array_failsafe);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        array[array_size-1] = x;
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "array[" << i << "] = " << array[i] << std::endl;
    }

    free(array); // Don't forget!

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You could, but this particular use of it has turned a linear time algorithm into a quadratic time algorithm. When you realloc you should *multiply* the current size by some factor (e.g. double it).

Comment: Yet a simple test run with 10k integers in a file ends up requiring 22 moves of data in the case of `realloc` and only 15 in the case of `std::vector<int>` (gcc/clang++ in macosx) causing worse performance. Basically you are trading the growth strategy in your standard implementation with the buckets in the allocator.

Comment: @john You're correct. I was just presenting the basic logic, though.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas And your point is? I never said `realloc()` is *the* way in C++; I think just the contrary! Use `vector` at absolutely all times. The OP, however, explicitly stated that he doesn't want one.

Comment: @hauzer: It is not a comment against your answer, just a general comment with the pros and cons of the different approaches. I have seen way too many people naively preferring lower level approaches (this question is one such) based on false performance assumptions. Given that you provided the `realloc` approach (and correctly!) this seemed to be the place for a comment on the costs of the two alternatives.

Comment: Do not use realloc in C++ code! Code such as in your example will make the project a maintenance nightmare.